# Activity's layout overwrites another activity's layout

Tags: java, android, xml

I have this weird problem that I have no idea where it's coming from.

I am making recipes app and I am using SQLite to display image, description and favorite check box. For recipe instructions I am not using SQLite , instead I am using TextView.

In my app I have two activities BreakfastActivity and Breakfast2Activity with their layouts that displays content which I mentioned above.The problem is that Breakfast Activity's XML code overwrites BreakfastActivity2 layout.

Note: The information that coming from database does't overwrite , but the one that comes from xml does.

I checked java activities if they use same layouts and if the layouts use the same context. Everything seems fine. I can't figure out where it can be potential problem.

Any Help would be appreciated.

This is `activity_breakfast xml`.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


    <ScrollView android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".BreakfastActivity">

        //I added shadow to the toolbar using design library

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            //I referenced other layout (tool bar layout)

            <include
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                layout="@layout/toolbar_main" />
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/photo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:maxWidth="600dp"
            android:maxHeight="300dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="#454444"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/instructionsText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:text="Instructions"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/instructionsStepsCrepes1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="@string/instructionsCrepesStep1"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/instructionsStepsCrepes2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="@string/instructionsCrepesStep1"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/instructionsStepsCrepes3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="@string/instructionsCrepesStep3"/>


        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/favorite"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/favorite"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:onClick="onFavoriteClicked"/>



        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
                android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:itemIconTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                app:itemTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu">

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="4dp"
                    android:layout_above="@id/bottom_navigation"
                    android:background="@drawable/shadow"/>

            </android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

This is `BreakfastActivity.java`

```
    public class BreakfastActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        public static final String EXTRA_BREAKFASTID ="breakfastId";
        private ShareActionProvider shareActionProvider;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_breakfast);
```

This is `activity_breakfast2 xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Breakfast2Activity">

    //I added shadow to the toolbar using design library

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        //I referenced other layout (tool bar layout)

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar_main" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photoBreakfast2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:maxWidth="600dp"
        android:maxHeight="300dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameBreakfast2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/descriptionBreakfast2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/instructionsText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:text="Instructions"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/instructionsStepsOmellete1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="@string/instructionsOmelleteStep1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/instructionsStepsOmellete2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="@string/instructionsOmelleteStep2"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/instructionsStepsOmellete3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="@string/instructionsOmelleteStep3"/>


    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/favorite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/favorite"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:onClick="onFavoriteClicked"/>


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" >

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="4dp"
                android:layout_above="@id/bottom_navigation"
                android:background="@drawable/shadow"/>



        </android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

this is `ActivityBreakfast2.java`

```
public class Breakfast2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String EXTRA_BREAKFAST2ID = "BREAKFAST2Id";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_breakfast2);
```

Comment: Might be because of _Translucent Activity_

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to ask a good question you should share enough code to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Comment: Please share proper code with screen shot.

Comment: I accidentally posted question, it is updated now.

Comment: Please add screenshot to show where is the problem

Comment: that is the thing that I don't know where exatcly is the problem. everything that I know and I have I already described above and gave screenshots. The main problem is that activity_breakfast xml overwrites activity_breakfast2 xml, it displays same layout elements that are in activity_breakfast.

Comment: Are you sure you're actually looking at `Breakfast2Activity`? Are you possibly starting the wrong `Activity`? Or maybe inadvertently starting `BreakfastActivity` again on top of `Breakfast2Activity`?